# White text in texture appears bigger than other colors, even without emitting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders

I'm struggling to get a consistent look for text on a book spline.
All colors looks ok and like the origin font, except white, which appears bolder, I assume due to some emission.
However, nothing I tried in the shader helped me overcome that. Even if the Principle BSDF roughness is set to 1.0.

I'm using a uv map for the text and a color mixer to control the text color over the base color.

How can I get the white text to not look oversized?

(I'm rendering with Cycles)

[image: The white and non white texts, notice how the white looks bolder]

[image: My shader]

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Non-Color" value in the texture node instead of "sRGB"?

Comment: Try using alpha instead of color under the color mixer Mix (Spline Text color). That should solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest working with a Map range after the Texture Image Node, and adjusting "From Min"-"To-Max" this might help improve the range, and use "Non-Color" colorspace for the Texrture mask

[image]

**Update**

Here, I found an interesting article in Italian (We can use Google Translate on the page) which explains the phenomenon called “Irradiation Phenomenon” or “Irradiation Illusion”.

In fact I checked your file, and the dimensions are actually the same, see for yourself in these 2 images. Take a look at the article it's very interesting

[Irradiation Illusion-Phenomenon article](https://www.grafigata.com/come-creare-versione-bianca-logo/)

[Irradiation Illusion From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irradiation_illusion)

In practice, white writing on a black background can appear larger than black writing on a white background due to this optical effect.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't do the trick. I tried adding the image as a plane and then shrinkwrap it to the face instead of doing it in the shader, and it results with the same problem. White looks much bolder than it should. 
Any other ideas?

Comment: @Boaz It would be helpful at this point for you to share the.blend file, remember to pack the textures if you want to do this. This would be useful to better understand the situation.

Comment: Thanks Cat for offering to take a look. Here's the file:https://drive.google.com/file/d/18gB1R9FHzBybMcqOBZ5sPOh1mxg3knsu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Boaz Take a look at my update

Comment: this is an unexpected twist. But you're right. Great job uncovering this, thanks!